# Periodically getting jQuery ".... is not a function" errors

Tags: jquery

I've been encountering a strange problem over the last week or 2 in that I keep periodically getting an `TypeError: jQuery(...).fullpage is not a function` error when trying to run a little script.

This primarily happens in Firefox, although I have noticed it (Albeit only once or twice) in Chrome and I'm at a loss as to why it's happening as I'm using the same theme framework as I have done for years and I've never had a problem with it before.

I'm enqueueing jQuery and my `script.js` file (Where I keep all my functions) correctly and below is a sample of the script I'm trying to run;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        scrollOverflow: 'true',
        sectionsColor: ['#f2f2f2', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#000'],
        anchors:['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'quatro'],
        normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 30,
    });

});
```

The issue only seems to happen when I'm trying to run a function that relies on another script, in this case it relies on a [full page script](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) (Which is also enqueued correctly).

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening? And why it seems to be almost exclusively limitied to Firefox?

Another thing to note, if you refresh the page a couple of times it seems to work again.

Edit : This is how I enqueue my scripts;

```
function child_theme_js() {

    if(!is_admin()) {

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        $scripts = array(
            'easing',
            'slimscroll.min',
            'fullpage.min',
            'script'
        );
        foreach ($scripts as $script){
            wp_register_script($script, get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/'.$script.'.js#asyncload', 'jquery', '', true);
            wp_enqueue_script($script);
        }

    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_js', 30);
```

I should have mentioned before, this is a child theme I am having issues with. The parent theme being a very basic starter theme (Some functions and basic CSS)

Comment: How are you enqueuing your `script.js`? Are you properly requiring the `.fullpage` jQuery plugin as a dependancy? Show is your enqueue.

Comment: The error is saying that `.fullpage()` is not defined, so make sure you are enqueueing that plugin.

Comment: I've edited my question to show how I enqueue things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your script loop is quite clever, it appears that the `fullscreen` script is not loading before your `script.js` is. Which is the problem. I would change your enqueues to this and try again.

After another glance, I believe the issue is that you have `fullpage.min` which is trying to be used as the ID of the script. I think that `.` is an invalid character, which would therefore not be enqueuing your script as it would fail on register.

Try this out, it should work. One thing to also consider is the fact that you look like you're using asyncronous JS loading. This means your `script.js` file, which is probably smaller than the assets it requires, is loading in first, meaning that `fullpage` is not ready yet. Try not using async, and instead enqueueing in the footer.

```
wp_register_script( 'easing', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/easing.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
wp_register_script( 'slimscroll', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slimscroll.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
wp_register_script( 'fullpage', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/fullpage.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.js', array( 'jquery', 'easing', 'slimscroll', 'fullpage' ), '', true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script' );
```

Comment: Aha!! It was the asynchronous loading that was the issue. I removed that and it works every time. Thanks so much, you've saved me countless grey hairs!!

Comment: :) I'd suggest keeping them as dependencies, just to ensure if you move things around later they will load properly. Also it shows you exactly what `my-script` requires. ;)